Consider blocklisting the [microsoft] tag?
As per Manufacturer & Company tags are back. Again, microsoft as a tag is not wanted: we have more specific tags to use for microsoft products (microsoft-excel, windows-10, etc).
It has been cleaned up, recreated, cleaned up again, and recreated again, with a current question count of 184. We also discussed blocking it in 2016 with an overwhelmingly positive response; a request to blocklist it was put to the CMs but never actioned.
We've also since blocked google: Blocklist Google? for the same problem - can we also consider adding the microsoft tag to the blocklist please?

heh, I was talking to someone about bulk tag cleanups and I wonder if a tag cleanup weekend might be a short term fix.

@JourneymanGeek Agreed. It could be time to revisit a cleanup event :)

@JourneymanGeek hey mate, given the positive response to this meta over the past two weeks (plus the positive response to the older one), do you think this is a good candidate to [status-review] for CMs to action?

Sure, lets give it a shot. ;)

As requested the tag has been blocked. I have added a warning to it that users should select a tag specific to the product they are using.

Looks like its happening. We'll try to trickle in edits over the next few days as time allows. In the interests of efficiency and less front page messiness we might be cleaning up unanswered questions with the tag as needed. If a question has merit, flag it linking this answer and we'll take a look

Looks like it's now blocked, I'm getting a red text error when attempting to add it to a question . Now we've just got to finish the cleanup/removal.

The cleanup has been completed!
